# diagonal matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

Can any body help to write a diagonal matrix **A** like this in R, please help in  this regard

```
> A
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    -1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]     0   -1    0    0    0    0
[3,]     0    0   -1    0    0    0 
[4,]     0    0    0   -1    0    0
[5,]     0    0    0    0   -1    0
[6,]     0    0    0    0    0   -1
[7,]     0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 4):

The matrix you have isn't exactly diagonal <s>since it isn't square</s>. However, you can see there's a diagonal matrix in there.

The following code reproduces the matrix

```
    A1 <- diag(-1,6) ## creates a 6x6 diag with -1 on the diag
    A2 <- c(rep(0,5),1) ## make the bottom row
    A <- rbind(A1,A2) ## put A1 on top of A2
```

Then you can see

```
    > A
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
     -1    0    0    0    0    0
      0   -1    0    0    0    0
      0    0   -1    0    0    0
      0    0    0   -1    0    0
      0    0    0    0   -1    0
      0    0    0    0    0   -1
A2    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix), a diagonal matrix does not necessarily need to be square (Today I Learned). Nevertheless, OPs matrix is indeed not diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((7,6))

j = 0
for i in range(6):
  A[j,i] = -1
  j= j+ 1

A[j,5] = 1

print(A)
```